# Unable to find utility "genstrings"

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, genstrings

I have an ios app and I now want to add a new language option.

I did localize my xibs and storyboards easily with "Localize" option at IB. But I also want to change my hardcoded strings in .m files. All sources I found says that I should use `"genstrings"`.

But when I try to use the command : `genstrings -o en.lproj *.m` at my project home directory, it gives me the error :

```
error: unable to find utility "genstrings", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I cannot find anything to solve this problem.
I also have developer tools, version of xcode : Version 6.3.2 .
Any help appreciated.

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? Have you installed command line tools?

Comment: Xcode version : Version 6.3.2 , yes i did it.

Comment: does `genstrings` live in your `/usr/bin` directory (which is where it lives for me)?  is `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Could you tell me how to check this ?